# how to update parent's state from child component along with passing some information from child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to build a portal where I have 3 components.

Parent component

->Child 1

->Child 2

From main component

-if (no files are selected) then GUI should show just the Child 1 and 
 Count and pathnames of files associated with Application

-else if (user has clicked on any file) then GUI should show the filename and 
 nodes associated to it.

I am trying to achieve this but i am confused in how to pass info from parent to child and vice versa.

In the code given below in Child 1.js when user click on path, the Parent component should update the GUI view by calling Child2 rather than calling Child1 .

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

For update parent component state from child component with arguments. You need to create method in parent component, that set state from arguments from this method. And pass this method to child component by props.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    state = {text: ""}

    updateText = text => {
        this.setState({text: text})
    }

    render () {
        return (<Child updateText={this.updateText}>)
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <button 
                onClick={
                    () => this.props.updateText("updated state from child component")
                }
            >Update State</button>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. But in my code as you can see in ApplicationList Child2 component,  i am trying to click on pathname and i want to send attribute value filename also to parent component. how would that be done?             x.section.map((y) => <p filename = {y.FileName} onClick = {}>{y.Path}</p>)

Comment: to be more clear, my question would be how to pass parameters to my handler.

Comment: (y) => <p onClick={() => this.props.updateText(y.FileName)}>{y.Path}</p>

Answer (score 2):

Building on what **galishmann** provided, just pass `y.Filename` to the function in props as it already expects a vlaue as a parameter.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    state = { text: "" }

    updateText = text => {
        this.setState({ text: text })
    }

    render() {
        return (<Child updateText={this.updateText} />)
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    ....
    ....
    ....

    render() {
        const { updateText } = this.props;
        const pathElement = this.state.groupedByAppName.map((x) => {
            return (
                <Collapsible trigger={x.AppName + '\t' + x.Count + ' files'} transitionTime={20}>
                    {
                        x.section.map((y) => <p filename={y.FileName} onClick={() => updateText(y.Filename)}>{y.Path}</p>)
                    }
                </Collapsible>
            )
        })
        return <div> {pathElement} </div>
    }
}
```